# AJAX - select field population with multiple values

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a form where the user can select ONE specific problem from a list of 100 problems. Once the `<Select id="problem">` field is updated, the below MySQL query is launched via AJAX.

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && ($_POST['action']=='problem_lookup')) {

    if(isset($_POST['problem'])) {

        // Start MySQLi connection
        include 'connect_db.php';
        $db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

        // display error if connection cannot be established
        if($db->connect_errno > 0){
        die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); }

        // run query
        $sql = "SELECT Category, Department_Responsible, Alert, Experience FROM qci_problems_index_new WHERE Issue='".$_POST['problem']."' GROUP BY Issue";
        $result = $db->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error($db));

        // return data as array
        $array = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo json_encode($array);
    }

}
```

the query returns several values which are each populated into individual `<select>` field in the form, the only exception is the `<select id="alert-dept" multiple>` field which can have multiple values and that's where the problem is.

Right now, all fields except `alert-dept` are populated with one specific value as intended, but in case the query returns 2 or more values, the field remains empty. I figure I have to use a `foreach()` equivalent for JavaScript when populating the field via AJAX, but am lost there as I dont know how to do that.

Here the code I use to populate the form fields with the query result.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">                                                 
$(function () {
    $('#problem').change(function () {                      // on change in field "problem"

        $.ajax({                                            // launch AJAX connection
            type: 'POST',                                   // via protocol POST
            url: '../../plugins/MySQL/ajax_action.php',
            data: { action: 'problem_lookup' , problem: $("#problem").val() },
            dataType: 'json',                               // encode with JSON
            success: function (data)
            {
                var data0 = data[0];                            // assign row[0] result to variable = Problem Category
                var data1 = data[1];                            // assign row[1] result to variable = Dept Responsible
                var data2 = data[2];                            // assign row[2] result to variable = Alert
                var data3 = data[3];                            // assign row[3] result to variable = Experience

                $('#problem_category').val(data0);              // insert result into field
                $('#department').val(data1);                    // insert result into field
                $('#alert_dept').val(data2);
                $('#experience').val(data3);

                $('#problem_category').trigger('change');       // refresh select field via trigger('change') to show the result
                $('#department').trigger('change'); 
                $('#alert_dept').trigger('change'); 
                $('#experience').trigger('change'); 
            },
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: So `data[2]` is an array like `['value1', 'value2', 'value3']` ?

Comment: Sorry, yes, forgot to mention its a comma seperated value. Eg. `'Person 1', 'Person 2', 'Person 3'`

Comment: I think i misread your question - does `alert-dept` already hold all the necessary options and that `data[2]` will have the set of values to select?

Comment: @RobinMackenzie yes, exactly that. I merely need the values in data[2] to be selected in the dropdown list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to target the right `option` in your select, based on the Ajax result...

Instead of:

```
$('#alert_dept').val(data2);
```

Try:

```
// Deselect all options just in case.
$('#alert_dept option').attr("selected",false);

data2.split(',').forEach(function(item) {

  // Select the options that match the ajax result.
  $('#alert_dept').find("option[value='"+item.trim()+"']").attr("selected",true);

});
```

Comment: Syntax error with `$('#alert_dept').find("option[value='"+item.trim()+"']).attr("selected",true);` somewhere around the closing bracket?

Comment: ?? Can you tell me what is the exact error message you have ?

Comment: Chrome Debugger says `missing ) on line 1512` which is `$('#alert_dept').find("option[value='"+item.trim()+"']).attr‌​("selected",true);` . I fiddled around with it but no matter where I place the `)` or `")` it doesnt work?

Comment: Argg... ok, What misses is not a `)` but a `"` here : `trim()+"']")`, right before the closing parenthesis. I edited.

Comment: Thanks for that, and sorry for the bother, I honestly have no clue about JS :)

Comment: Let me know if there some new bugs... If it works, consider accepting the answer! ;)